# rollback in tfs2008 with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rollback

I have Visual studio 2010 that work with TFS 2008.
How Do I Use Rollback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rollback in Visual Studio TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276780/how-to-rollback-in-visual-studio-tfs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. The Team Foundation Power Tools for 2010 no longer has the rollback command because it is now integrated into tf.exe (the TFS 2010 client command line that comes with VS2010). But tf rollback does not work against TFS 2008.

You're only real solution (that I know of) is to do a manual checkout of the old version and then check it back in as the new version, but this can be a real hassle, especially for undoing merges.

Answer (score 0):

On a spare machine install Visual Studio Team Explorer 2008 and Team Foundation Power Tools 2008 and then use the tfpt rollback command.