# Undo accidental check-in with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rollback in Visual Studio TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276780/how-to-rollback-in-visual-studio-tfs)

I need to undo my check-in in TFS.

How do I go about?
where can i read up on how to do it please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found plenty of examples, i did not search for it correctly

[How to rollback in Visual Studio TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276780/how-to-rollback-in-visual-studio-tfs)

[How do I rollback a TFS check-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607/how-do-i-rollback-a-tfs-check-in)

Comment: it might nevertheless be usefull to put the answer here, because people might search for this topic on SO and be dissapointed that you have an answer but didn't share it ;-)

Comment: But if I rollback my changes then they are gone locally. I have accidentally checked in half my work.